# Unable to change the background color of navbar to a custom using css in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to change the color of the navbar using a custom color with css but so far no luck, I even went through various searches but those do not work as well. I've used navbar, navbar-custom, and other names to try and modify the color in css but none work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Blog</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vSIIfh2YWi9wW0r9iZe7RJPrKwp6bG+s9QZMoITbCckVJqGCCRhc+ccxNcdpHuYu" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="title">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-lg">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Blog</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">

        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </div>

  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-custom{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: it works fine: https://codeply.com/p/2YG6DfrHHA

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zdvprmuh/ Your code as is seems to work for me.

Comment: Hmmm, thats strange it doesnt show the change at all for me in my chrome browser..

Answer (score 0):

I've forgotten to put it styles.css in the css folder.